# How can I read and write to pipes created for a child process in c++

Tags: c++, c++20, named-pipes

I am making a tester program that opens a console application and reads it's standard input writes to it's standard output, but am having issues with the pipes. I am using named pipes since I might have to run this threaded or even open multiple executables to communicate with at once. These will need to remain running and continuously take input and give out put, as in a console calculator that asks if you if you want another calculation or to exit after each calculation.

Using error checking I have found that The pipes are created successfully, I apply them to the startupInfo struct and successfully open the executable. A note here, if I set a break point in visual studio just after the call to createProcess, the child process does show up in my task manager, the check STILL_ACTIVE is true and peaking at the pipe reveals an empty pipe. If no break point is set then I don't see it, and the check STILL_ACTIVE is false.

To simplify the problem I went back to basics, a simple hello world executable in c++. The calculator will be the next test. This prints hello world to the console and via a cin:get() waits for the enter key to be pressed. I ran this with the tester and tried to read the "Hello World" from the child process. I get nothing.

The end project will be open source, I don't want the user to have to download any other libraries to compile the project, and Boost::Process actually requires 2 install since process is not standard yet.

I know that I am close, here is my simple tester as one file with the process class extracted to be inline in the main. Note: I have enabled c++20 in my compiler.

```
// Tester.cpp 
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::string data = "";
    int id = 1;
    std::string executable = "HelloWorld.exe";

    if (_access((executable).c_str(), 0) != -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Executable file not found: " << executable << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr{};
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    //Pipe names
    std::wstring pipeErr = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\err_" + std::to_wstring(id);
    std::wstring pipeOut = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\out_" + std::to_wstring(id);
    std::wstring pipeIn = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\in_" + std::to_wstring(id);    

    // The Child error pipe for reading
    CreateNamedPipeW(pipeErr.c_str(), PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, 1024, 1024, 0, NULL);
    HANDLE err_pipe = CreateFileW(pipeErr.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &saAttr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);

    // The Child out pipe for reading
    CreateNamedPipeW(pipeOut.c_str(), PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, 1024, 1024, 0, NULL);
    HANDLE out_pipe = CreateFileW(pipeOut.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &saAttr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    
    // The Child in pipe for writing
    CreateNamedPipeW(pipeIn.c_str(), PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, 1024, 1024, 0, NULL);
    HANDLE in_pipe = CreateFileW(pipeIn.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &saAttr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    
    if (in_pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || out_pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || err_pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "Error Creating Handles, Code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Make sure the handles' inheritance is set correctly
    if (!SetHandleInformation(in_pipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT) ||
        !SetHandleInformation(out_pipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT) ||
        !SetHandleInformation(err_pipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Failed to set handle information for the child process" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Set up the startup info struct
    STARTUPINFOA startupInfo;
    memset(&startupInfo, 0, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA);
    startupInfo.hStdInput = in_pipe;
    startupInfo.hStdOutput = out_pipe;
    startupInfo.hStdError = err_pipe;
    startupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    
    // Set up the process info struct
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    memset(&processInfo, 0, sizeof(processInfo));
    
    // Create the child process
    if (CreateProcessA(NULL, executable.data(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInfo) == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Failed to create the child process" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Set the pipes to non-blocking mode
    DWORD mode = PIPE_NOWAIT;
    SetNamedPipeHandleState(out_pipe, &mode, NULL, NULL);
    SetNamedPipeHandleState(err_pipe, &mode, NULL, NULL);
    SetNamedPipeHandleState(in_pipe, &mode, NULL, NULL);

    Sleep(500); //wait for child to start, may not be neccesary
    
    // Get the exit code of the child process
    DWORD exitCode;
    GetExitCodeProcess(processInfo.hProcess, &exitCode);

    if (exitCode == STILL_ACTIVE) {
        // Set up the read buffer
        char buffer[1024];
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        DWORD bytesRead = 0;
        DWORD bytesAvail = 0;

        // Check if there is data available to read from the pipe
        if (!PeekNamedPipe(out_pipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, &bytesAvail, NULL)) {
            std::cerr << "PeekNamedPipe failed (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
            return 0;
        }

        if (bytesAvail == 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Pipe is empty" << std::endl;
        }

        if (!ReadFile(out_pipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &bytesRead, NULL))
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to read from pipe. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        data = buffer;

    }
    if (data == "") {
        std::cout << "Something went wrong. Code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Press any key." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

and, for reference, here is helloworld.exe:

```
// HelloWorld.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: You are losing pipe handles returned by `CreateNamedPipe`. You only have access to one end of the pipe. What is written into, say, `out_pipe` should be read from the handle returned by `CreateNamedPipeW(pipeOut.c_str(), ...)` call - but you don't preserve that handle.

Comment: You likely don't want `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE`, unless the child program is specifically designed to write messages. For one thing, the documentation says "The client side of a named pipe starts out in byte mode, even if the server side is in message mode. To avoid problems receiving data, set the client side to message mode as well"; you don't do that. But even if you did - you have a child program that writes through the standard library. There's buffering involved - it would be difficult to predict when the CRT decides to write to the underlying handle. You won't have meaningful message bounds.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation for why you want named pipes, rather than anonymous (see e.g. [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)). Neither "run this threaded" nor "open multiple executables to communicate with at once" precludes the use of anonymous pipes.

Comment: I am remaking https://github.com/dreignier/cg-brutaltester in c++. The Java version does not compile due to outdated libraries being used. I wanted to do something more future proof, hence no 3rd party Libraries and starting from scratch. The result will be uploaded back to github. I already wrote and tested the other classes, and decided to test my Process class by just finishing up the little remaining communication code and got no joy. I posted this all in my first question but the mods wouldn't let it post because it was too "vague" so I re-posted the question with just the basics.

Comment: The Brutal Tester used two communication types. The "old" mode opens a referee executable and 2 or 4 player executables (up to 6 child processes!). Then, it "facilitates" the communication between the referee and the players passing messages back and forth. The "new" mode only opens the Referee sending in the Player executables as command line arguments, the Referee handles the rest and send the scores back to the Brutal Tester. The Referee files already exist, some player files are available to download but basically you use your code from https://www.codingame.com/ as the player file.

Comment: @igor "this sample" does not handle the case where the player files just use cin/cout/cerr, as on codingame. Trying your other suggestions now...

Comment: What do you mean, does not handle? In what way does it fall short of your requirements? It uses the same handle for both stdout and stderr; that's easy to fix, just create another pipe the same way. The child process created this way doesn't need to do anything special, it would just read from standard input and write to standard output. I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Igor Tandetnik!

Here is the working Tester.cpp:

```
// Tester.cpp 
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <aclapi.h>

constexpr auto BUFSIZE = 4096;

int main()
{
    std::string data = "";
    int id = 1;
    std::wstring executable = L"HelloWorld.exe";
    std::wstring argv = L"";
    
    std::string name_c = "";
    std::string path_c = "";

    HANDLE hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
    HANDLE hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;
    HANDLE hChildStd_ERR_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE hChildStd_ERR_Wr = NULL;

    size_t size;
    wcstombs_s(&size, nullptr, 0, executable.c_str(), executable.length());
    name_c.resize(size);
    wcstombs_s(&size, name_c.data(), name_c.size(), executable.c_str(), executable.length());

    wchar_t current_dir[FILENAME_MAX];
    if (_wgetcwd(current_dir, FILENAME_MAX) == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Error getting current working directory. Code:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    wchar_t path_exe[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, path_exe, MAX_PATH);
    std::wstring path = path_exe;
    path = std::filesystem::path(path).parent_path();
    path += L"\\";
    path += executable;

    wcstombs_s(&size, nullptr, 0, path.c_str(), path.length());
    path_c.resize(size);
    wcstombs_s(&size, path_c.data(), path_c.size(), path.c_str(), path.length());

    int found = _waccess_s(path.c_str(), 0);
    if (found != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Executable file not found: " << name_c << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa_attr{};
    sa_attr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa_attr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa_attr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create the pipes
    if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &sa_attr, 0)
        || !CreatePipe(&hChildStd_IN_Rd, &hChildStd_IN_Wr, &sa_attr, 0)
        || !CreatePipe(&hChildStd_ERR_Rd, &hChildStd_ERR_Wr, &sa_attr, 0)) {
        std::cout << "Error Creating Pipes, Code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (hChildStd_OUT_Rd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hChildStd_OUT_Wr == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE 
        || hChildStd_IN_Rd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hChildStd_IN_Wr == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
        || hChildStd_ERR_Rd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hChildStd_ERR_Wr == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "Error Creating Handles, Code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up the startup info struct
    STARTUPINFOW startup_info;
    ZeroMemory(&startup_info, sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));
    startup_info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);
    startup_info.hStdOutput = hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    startup_info.hStdError = hChildStd_ERR_Wr;
    startup_info.hStdInput = hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    startup_info.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    
    // Set up the process info struct
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info;
    memset(&process_info, 0, sizeof(process_info));
    
    // Create the child process
    if (!CreateProcess(path.data(), NULL, &sa_attr, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, &process_info))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Failed to create the child process. Code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the exit code of the child process
    DWORD exitCode;
    GetExitCodeProcess(process_info.hProcess, &exitCode);

    if (exitCode != STILL_ACTIVE) {
        std::wcout << "Unable to Start Process: " << executable.c_str() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::wcout << "Started Process: " << executable.c_str() << std::endl;

   Sleep(500); //wait for child to start, may not be neccesary
    
    // Get the exit code of the child process
    GetExitCodeProcess(process_info.hProcess, &exitCode);

    if (exitCode == STILL_ACTIVE) {
        // Set up the read buffer
        DWORD bytesRead{}, dwWritten{};
        CHAR buffer[BUFSIZE]{};
        BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
        HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        bSuccess = ReadFile(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buffer, BUFSIZE, &bytesRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess || bytesRead == 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to read from pipe. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        std::vector<char> v_data(buffer, buffer + bytesRead);
        data = std::string(v_data.data(), v_data.size());

    }
    std::cout << "Recieved from Child: " << data << std::endl;
    if (data == "") {
        std::cout << "Something went wrong. Code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
    CloseHandle(process_info.hThread);
    std::cout << "Press any key." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you would like this as a Process class to use in your own projects, you can find it in the sources files here: https://github.com/Akadine/new-cg-brutaltester